# stage.setIconify(true) doesn't work with undecorated stage

Tags: java, javafx

I have an undecorated FXML stage. I created a button to minimize window and created an event for it in Controller class in initialize method.

```
minimizeBtn.setOnAction(e -> {


            Stage stage = (Stage)((Button)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setIconified(true);
            System.out.println(stage.isIconified());
        });
```

Problem:

`isIconified()` returns `true`, while nothing happens to window visually.

If I switch from UNDECORATED to default my custom button perfectly works.

Comment: Hello, I suggest that you read through [mcve] and then provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that demonstrates the problem. With that said, I had no problems with minimizing when I modified one of my own projects to do this. I copied your code. What Java version do you use?

Comment: It works on my environment. Please add an MCVE and other information like your Java version, the JavaFX one, the OS on which it does not work.

Comment: JDK 11, JavaFX 11.0.2, MacOS High Sierra. I tried to create new empty Gradle project and just create a stage with one button that minimizes it and it did't work.

Comment: "_and it did't work_". Do you mean you can't reproduce the problem or you did reproduce the problem and the minimizing didn't work? If it's the latter, [edit] your question and add your [mcve]. You should also edit the question to provide the version information; that way all the pertinent information is in the question itself, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me on both MacOS High Sierra and Mojave, with jdk 11.0.2 and JavaFX 12.0.1
There's the example code to reproduce the issue.
Note that without setting the `UNDECORATED` style to the stage the problem doesnt' happen.
On Windows the behaviour is correct no matter what the stage style is.

```
public class DemoApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      Button minimize = new Button("MINIMIZE");
      minimize.setOnAction(event -> primaryStage.setIconified(true));
      primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

      Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(minimize));
      primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX App");
      primaryStage.setWidth(960);
      primaryStage.setHeight(600);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

}
```